# How many times did Emmett Brown travel through time?

Tags: back-to-the-future

There are many clues suggesting that Emmett Brown traveled through time on multiple occasions.

**I was thinking about the case full of dollars from different periods:**

[image]

Is it possible to get them at one specific moment, or go to different periods and earn them in some way?

Is there a story or estimation on how many times Emmett Brown traveled through time?

Comment: You can get them NOW from coin/note dealers...you'll just pay over the face value.

Comment: Pretty complete answer over on SF&F regarding the money - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/91508/where-did-doc-get-his-money-collection-from

Comment: Are you asking just about the three films? Or do you also include the TV show? Or the various video games?

Comment: The TV shows take place after the movie, and obviously there are many travels at this time. I was more interested in the time frame from the movies (from the invention to the destruction of the De Lorean). Other people might be interested in other parts though.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to get them at one specific moment, or go to different periods and earn them in some way?

Yes. You can get good condition old series bills today without much issue. The older the more valuable though
 You can easily counterfeit older bills, as technology has surpassed the contemporary anti-counterfeit techniques the bills were designed with. And as Doc has traveled into the future and retrieved technology from it, he likely has something akin to a perfect printer. And valuables to trade in the present day (much like Biff used the Almanac).

Notice Doc doesn't have any bills newer than modern day. He was simply preparing for any potential time travel, instead of acquiring it at the time period they came out.

Comment: This is convincing about the bills. But it says little about travels. For example we know he went to the future and saw Marty's future. Was it a one shot? As far as I remember, Doc never mentioned going to the past. Are there other clues?